# The detail of External PCIe cabling specification?

Tags: pcie, pci

As searching on the Internet, I found that the PCI group has released the "PCIe External cabling specifications". But I can not download the document because I am not a member of the PCI group. So, please help me explain these PCIe to MiniSAS HD's signals below :

- PWR
- MGTPWR
- CBLPRSNT#
- CADDR
- CINT#
- CMISDA
- CMISCL

Can anyone share the document or reference design?

Answer (score 1):

From [this user guide](https://www.dolphinics.com/download/MX/OPEN_DOC/MXH830_users_guide.pdf) for an external PCIe product, it describes the signals as follows:

> - PWR: Power to support AOC and signal conditioning components within the cable assembly.
> - MGTPWR: Power supplied to the connector for cable management components that are needed while the link is not active. This needs to be active if the subsystem has power.
> - CBLPRSNT#: Cable present detect, an active-low signal pulled-down by the cable when it is inserted into the connector.
> - CADDR: Signal used to configure the upstream cable management device address.
> - CINT#: Signal asserted by the cable assembly to indicate a need for service via the CMI controller.
> - CMISDA: Management interface data line. Used for both initial link setup and sideband messages when used with CMI compliant cables.
> - CMISCL: Management interface clock line. Used for both initial link setup and sideband messages when used with CMI compliant cables.

Comment: Yes, thanks so much. But, How can I design with these signals? Can you share with me the PCIe external cabling specifications?